# Apache Pig needlessly re-running map reduce jobs

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

A few times I've had pig workflows where I store multiple aliases. For example, I'll have something roughly like

```
A = LOAD 'data1' USING PigStorage()
B = LOAD 'data2' USING PigStorage()
C = ... # transformation of A
D = ... #transformation of B
E = JOIN C by fieldA, D by fieldB
# STORE E into 'foo'
F = ... # transformation of E
STORE F into 'bar'
```

I would think that if I un-commented storing E, it would add only one map-reduce job since the results of E should already be in a temporary hadoop output file. In practice, it always adds multiple jobs, as if pig is reloading A and B and recomputing E from scratch.

When does Pig need to do this, and how do you prevent it?

Using version 0.11.0.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have [Multi-Query Optimization](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.0/perf.html#multi-query-execution) enabled and that you are running this script like

```
bash> pig script.pig
```

rather than copying and pasting the code into the Grunt shell.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I haven't touched the default for Multi-Query response so I suspect it's turned on, but I'll check to be sure. I'm running the script through the Java PigServer class's registerScript function with the input stream overload.